# C# - Read local download path on file download

Tags: c#, download

For a c# web application, we would like to create the possibility to download a file. If *User 1* downloads file *MyFileToDownload.txt*, we would like to show the local saving directory on our website. 
For instance if he downloads MyFileToDownload.txt we want to show a message like: "*File MyFileToDownload.txt is locked by User 1 in directory 'Downloads'*".

So my question now: Is it possible to read the local saving location from a user? Or is the File anyway always saved in the directory *Downloads* on the most common operating systems such like "Windows and MacOs"

Our File download Code:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyFileToDownload.txt");
Response.TransmitFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\MyFileToDownload.txt");
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser won't supply that information to you as it would represent a security risk to the user.

Whilst there are default download locations (on most recent version of Windows it's the Downloads folder in the user folder, for instance), all browsers allow users to choose another location should they wish to.